# React-router and jsx-no-bind

Tags: react-router, reactjs, jsx

I'm using `react-router` to do navigation. I have some components that are requiring a login before they can be seen.

Therefore I have this: (from following documentation in react-router)

```
<Route
  {...rest}
  render={props =>
    isLoggedIn()
      ? <Component {...props} />
      : <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: {from: props.location},
          }}
        />}
/>
```

However, there is a problem with this, since `jsx-no-bind` disallows arrow functions. What is the correct way around this? Or should this simply be ignored because it for some reason does not suffer the same performance hits?

Comment: Any new on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Official React documentation on render props:

https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html

This documentation uses examples like:

`<DataProvider render={data => (
  <h1>Hello {data.target}</h1>
)}/>`

Be aware of caveats as mentioned here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#caveats

This includes the use of PureComponents